# how to restore wordpress backup(.rar) manually?

Tags: plugins, php, backup

I have a WordPress backup file(.rar) which was taken 3 years back and I don't know how or using which plugin(Someone else did that). I need to restore the file to my new WordPress site.

I have used many plugins and so far it has been a failure. Most of them need to be premium to restore the backup. I don't have phpMyAdmin or any other control panel too.

**Is there any other way to restore the backup file to my site?**

I am a beginner in WordPress and php. I really need help.

Comment: do you have a database backup? probably it's in .sql format or inside .zip container

Comment: Yes i have a .zip file. But how do i restore it? @Vishwa

Comment: in where do you need to use it? do you have a local development environment? (xampp installation may be)

Comment: I have hosted my WordPress site on my server. But I have backup in my local system. I am doing all the testing in the local system. There are other sites hosted in the server. Restoring may affect them(Not sure). Can and Should I restore it locally? @Vishwa

Comment: `.rar` is a compressed directory just like a `.zip`, although it's not as common as `.tar` or `.gz`. Unpackage it and see what's inside. You'll probably have to copy the files/directories and the database into the appropriate places once it's unpackaged.

Answer (score 0):

As MikeNGarrett said, you need to look inside your `rar` file to see what's inside.

This is basic procedure. Go to your public folder (htdocs for xampp), and create a directory(yourprojectfolder). Extract your `rar` file inside it. if you can see folders like wp-content, wp-includes and files like wp.config.php etc.. then you've done first part.

Then access your local `phpmyadmin` (usually http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ ). create a new database, then import from your backup (either `.sql`file or `.zip`file which has sql file inside).

After import finishes, open table `wp-options`(note: the wp part could be different). then change siteurl and homepage url to http://localhost/yourprojectfolder.

Then open `wp-config.php` and give proper credentials on database details. you're done. now you can access your wp site by http://localhost/yourprojectfolder/